# match the label and get value from Labelvaluebean

Tags: java

I'm getting a list of organization type and code are stored as labelvaluebean as below:
[LabelValueBean[ORG1, XX], [ORG2, AA]] - in array.

later these values are stored in a session variable. My question is, is there a way I can search thru this array to match the name and get the code ? (for ex: match with ORG1 and get XX). If user enter ORG1, I should send XX to back-end.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want to be using a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead of an array. A `Map` will store...mappings...between keys and values - think of it like a table with 2 columns, where the first column is your organization type and the second column is the code. You then take an organization code, look in your table at the values in the first column until you find a match, then you look over at the second column for the code, and return it. Obviously, this is handled by the `Map` implementation used, so all you need to do is declare what `Objects` should be used as the keys and values. In your case, maybe you'll have a `Map<String, String>`.

For example,

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("ORG1", "XX");
map.put("ORG2", "AA");
map.get("ORG1") // returns "XX"
map.get("ORG2") // returns "AA"
```

Comment: The code is already there to get orgtype and code into an array. how to store it into a map ?